# use different shapes and color in using subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have two sets of data with two columns date and rainfall. I used for loop to get codes for each datasets and then use subplots to plot them. But both data sets has same color and hence impossible to compare them. So how to use different color and shapes to for each datasets. Also how to give different legends as a whole for two data sets so that let's say red for data sets one and blue for datasets two and use same color in sub plots also.

```py
fig, (fig1,fig2,fig3,fig4) = plt.subplots(4, figsize=(16,14))

for fin in os.listdir(directory):
    if fin.endswith(".txt"):
       GNSS = fin[0:4]    # station name, e.g., UH01
       ts_enu = []
       ts_enu = pd.read_csv (fin, header=0, delim_whitespace=True)
       year = ts_enu.iloc[:,0]    # decimal year
       rain = ts_enu.iloc[:,1]     # NS
       cal_95CI(year,rain)
else:
   pass

fig.savefig('_Decomposition.pdf') 
plt.show()
```

and the function modules is

```py
def cal_95CI(year,rain):
    fig1.plot(year, rain)
    fig2.plot(year,rain)   
    fig3.plot(year, rain)
    fig4.plot(year, rain)`
```

and the output is
[image]

Clearly there are two datapoints in image but both are same color. this is edited code. The main working code is https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1k5QNfdppPQDiK9TICPgmDpLYx5zjItmJ?usp=sharing

I used

```py
def cal_95CI(year,rain):
    plt.plot(year,rain)`
```

it clearly shows graph with two different colors. but when I use subplot, it graph appears in same color.

Comment: Due to security concerns, people will not download unknown data from an unknown drive. You should instead build a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces you issue, with synthetic data. Also, doing this solves a large proportion of issues beforehand. Please try to edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that on your first `cal_95CI`, you specify colors for each plot `call`, which is the reason you have the same colour for both datasets. NOt the difference with your second  `cal_95CI`.

Comment: Given the existing code, the issue is not reproducible: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7181M.png) each plot is dataset is colored separately in each plot.

Comment: In any case, the included code can be reduced to 5 lines (not including formatting and adding regression lines, which isn't shown) if you would follow the examples provided in your previous questions: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRMhs.png)